# Change contact form validation

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, prototype-js

I would like to do a blur check on the contact form, but it only does the validation on the submit, I would like to know how I make this change.

**I'm trying like this**

```
    $j('contactForm').blur(function () {
          if (contactForm.validator.validate()) {
              alert('ok');
          } else {
              alert('no')
          }
     });
```

But I think I'd have to change the natural code for magento, right?

```
VarienForm = Class.create();
VarienForm.prototype = {
    initialize: function(formId, firstFieldFocus){
        this.form       = $(formId);
        if (!this.form) {
            return;
        }
        this.cache      = $A();
        this.currLoader = false;
        this.currDataIndex = false;
        this.validator  = new Validation(this.form);
        this.elementFocus   = this.elementOnFocus.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.elementBlur    = this.elementOnBlur.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.childLoader    = this.onChangeChildLoad.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.highlightClass = 'highlight';
        this.extraChildParams = '';
        this.firstFieldFocus= firstFieldFocus || false;
        this.bindElements();
        if(this.firstFieldFocus){
            try{
                Form.Element.focus(Form.findFirstElement(this.form))
            }
            catch(e){}
        }
    },

    submit : function(url){
        if(this.validator && this.validator.validate()){
             this.form.submit();
        }
        return false;
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the contact form phml file and add your script there.

Add it as

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    $(function () { // to ensure that code evaluates on page load

    $j('contactForm').blur(function () {
      if (contactForm.validator.validate()) {
        alert('ok');
      } else {
       alert('no')
      }
    });


  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is what I did, I would like to do the fields validation in the blur, but it already has a validation done, only that is only in the submit, I would like to change it and put it in the blur ..